# How to support multiple environments on iOS with React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to support dev, staging and prod environments. My question is how to correctly use xcode schemes, targets and build configurations to do this. I am using react-native-config and I have created my various .env files e.g .env.dev.

To my knowledge there are two ways to accomplish this:

Create a scheme and debug and release build configurations for each env.
For example for the dev env:
AppDev scheme, which uses DevDebug and DevRelease build configurations. These build configurations are created as duplicates of the default Debug and Release configurations.
Note there is only a single target, which is the original one that the project comes with.

Create a schema and target for each env. Each target has its own Debug and Release build configurations.
For example for the dev env:
AppDev scheme and AppDev target with Debug and Release build configurations.

I feel like method 1 is more correct. I have previously worked on a project several years ago that used this method using React Native 0.59. However I am unable to get this to work on a brand new app I created using React Native 0.71.3. The app crashes on launch immediately. I can post the error details if required but it just looks like a pretty generic fatal crash. On the other hand a lot of tutorials I see online use method 2. I can also get this method to work. Is anyone able to provide a suggestion as to which method is correct and preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You can archive that using this library '[react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)' for more information about how to implement it and using it on android and iOS you can check this [medium article](https://ajaysidhu17.medium.com/configure-production-and-staging-environments-in-react-native-6c0d0faad034).